# ActiveRecord and use of has_one & has_many

Tags: ruby, activerecord, has-many, has-one

Consider this simple model, where a `Project` has one `ProjectType` and, naturally many `Projects` can be of that type.

So a `Project` `has_one :project_type` (called `type`) and a `ProjectType` `has_many :projects`.

In my migration I put (simplified for this example)

```
create_table :projects do |t|
  t.string :name, :null => false
  t.integer :type
end

create_table :project_types do |t|
  t.string :name, :null => false
end
```

My Project class looks like this (again simplified for this example)

```
#!usr/bin/ruby
require 'active_record'

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :type, :class_name => 'ProjectType'
end
```

And my ProjectType looks like

```
#!usr/bin/ruby
require 'active_record'

class ProjectType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

I've written a simple Unit Test to check this works

```
#test creation of Projects and related objects.
def test_projects_and_etc  
  pt = ProjectType.create(:name => 'Test PT')
  project = Project.create(:name => 'Test Project', :type => pt)
  assert project.type.name == 'Test PT', "Wrong Project Type Name, expected 'Test PT' but got '#{project.type.name}'."

  # clean up
  project.destroy
  pt.destroy
end
```

This test throws an error at the assert, saying

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: project_types.project_id: SELECT  "project_types".* FROM "project_types" WHERE ("project_types".project_id = 1) LIMIT 1
```

The SQL seems to be assuming that there is a `project_id` field in the `project_types` table but that makes no sense if a `ProjectType` can be associated with many `Projects`.  I suspect that my problem is something to do with my wanting to be able to refer to the `ProjectType` as `project.type` not `project.project_type`, but I am not sure how I'd fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use belongs_to instead of has_one on the project model.

You also need to add a project_type_id column on to the projects table.

Comment: Okay so further reading tells me that `has_one` is strictly for 1:1 relationships and not what i am trying to do, so that makes sense, if a little linguistically weird that now a `Project` belongs to a `ProjectType`.  Re adding a `project_type_id`, what if I want the field to be called `type` not `project_type`? Is it enough to change `t.integer type` to `t.integer type_id` and if so what do I add to my model? I've tried making those changes and now my test throws an error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I've also now tried your suggestion of changing the migration to read `t.integer project_type_id` in the `projects` table but I get exactly the same error.

Comment: Did you rollback and rerun the migration now that you've modified it?  Did you also specify:
`belongs_to :project_type`
on the project model?

As for calling it "type", that's a reserved word used for single table inheritance, so don't do it.

Comment: Also, in your tests, specify:
`project = Project.create(:name => 'Test Project', :project_type => pt)
assert project.project_type.name == 'Test Pt', "Wrong Project Type Name, expected 'Test PT' but got '#{project.project_type.name}'."`

i.e. use `:project_type` instead of `:type`

Comment: Great, that works.  My problem was wanting to use `type` as a field name and not twigging that it is a reserved word. (should have been obvious really).  Many thanks.